# Rsync only receiving file list between two debian servers, not copying

Tags: debian, rsync

I'm copying items from one debian server to another and trying to use Rsync for the process. I had issues getting it working over 10GB lanes but finally fixed that. My issue now is the command is coming back with 'Receiving incremental file list' and then quits but nothing is copied.
For reference, if I ssh into either one I land in the root folder and have to do cd ../srv/disk/ in order to get into my shares. On the destination server (in the command below) I have an empty directory called Music. The source server has the Music directory full of folders and files and I'm trying to copy all contents into the empty Music folder on the dest.

The command:

```
rsync \
  -ahP \
  --chmod=D777,F666 \
  --address=10.10.10.15:./srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music/ \
  root@10.10.10.13:/srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music
```

is coming back with:

```
receiving incremental file list
drwxrwxrwx          4.10K 2022/12/18 13:00:29 Music
What am I doing wrong?
```

UPDATE:
I've got things running now but speeds are much lower than I'd imagined (no higher than 15MB/s on files ranging from 25MB to 125MB)

```
   -hazP \
   --stats\
   -e "ssh -T -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com -o Compression=no -x"\     
root@10.10.10.15:/srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/ \
/srv/mergerfs/norman_pool2/media
```

Comment: Can you add in some verbosity and get some more information?

Comment: @BowlOfRed I've added verbosity now but I did get it running finally, the issue is my speeds now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all convinced about your use of `--address=10.10.10.15:./srv/…`. I think that should be `--address=10.10.10.15 srv/…`:

```
rsync \
  -ahP \
  --chmod=D777,F666 \
  --address=10.10.10.15 \
  srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music/ \
  root@10.10.10.13:/srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music
```

Or even just omit `--address=10.10.10.15` entirely:

```
rsync \
  -ahP \
  --chmod=D777,F666 \
  srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music/ \
  root@10.10.10.13:/srv/27829c9c-dbc1-4408-a111-56dbcd8f0ec0/media/Music
```

Comment: I'll try that, I didn't want to omit it because I want to force the command to only go through the 10Gb portw

Comment: @Geoff_S modified - try that